# Optimization metrics for a single-item recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, probability, optimization, recommender-system, ab-test

I'm working on a recommendation system that's a bit different from ones I've built before. In particular, this system shows only the top item to the user, and the user can either click on it, dismiss it, or ignore it.

We have two datasets - one biased by a previous model, and one that randomly selects an item and shows it to a small fraction of sessions.

Normally, I would use something like MAP or MRR for an optimization metric, but in this case, there is no way for a user to click on an item that is not the top recommended item, so we have no knowledge of whether our sorting is wrong. Something like precision could work, but I am worried that this will lead to unbalanced predictions.

Our goal is to make good predictions, but also not to fall into a trap of only recommending the item with the highest CTR. If we had an oracle of whether the user would click a given item, we would build a model that randomly selects between those.

Is there a name for this class of problem, and are there any solid metrics we could use here?

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between dismissing and ignoring for the recommendation maker? Are the payoffs different?

Comment: For this question, there is no difference - are thinking of them both as "no click." Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: And you want to use this data to build a new CTR prediction model and make sure it performs better than the old one, either off-line or though an A/B test, as measured by a TBD performance criterion?

Comment: Yup, eventually we'll perform an AB test that measures CTR increases for the difference classes. I'm looking for a performance criterion that I can use for offline backtesting here.